# Watir: Suppressing object timeout to favor my own error

Tags: ruby, watir, error-suppression

I am working with an automation framework that deals with hundreds of test cases, and once all the scripts are written - thousands. The application under test has an error page that displays when there is an internal error, which results in our normal friendly error of object time-out, because Watir cannot find the object in question:

```
  1) Error:
Test_Case#test_case:
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:xpath=>"//small[@class=\"total-card-value\"]"} to become present
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:48:in `until'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:120:in `method_missing'
    C:/workspace/Automated_Test_Scripts/trunk/Phoenix/classes/sidebar.rb:85:in `get_total_card_value'
    C:/workspace/Automated_Test_Scripts/trunk/Phoenix/classes/sidebar.rb:65:in `check_total'
    C:/workspace/Automated_Test_Scripts/trunk/Phoenix/tests/Reloadable_Payment.rb:116:in `block in test_case'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.12/lib/mysql.rb:675:in `call'
    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.12/lib/mysql.rb:675:in `each'
    C:/workspace/Automated_Test_Scripts/trunk/Phoenix/tests/Reloadable_Payment.rb:50:in `test_case'
```

This Watir error does not accurately tell me what happened during test execution, because the page redirected to the error page in this example. I want to de-clutter my logs and prevent showing the Watir error and instead display a custom error message:

```
  if $b.text.include?("We're sorry, but something went wrong.")
    puts "\033[1;31;40m Phoenix has stopped responding and is showing the \"We're sorry...\" message. Please e-mail these test log steps to the Phoenix group.\033[0m"
  end
```

When I added this to the teardown (Minitest::Unit), it shows up as I anticipated but it also shows the timeout error regardless of what I try based on other examples out there for faulty page loading.

How do I suppress the object timeout error when I want to present this specific error in my logs?

Comment: Are you using Watir or Watir-Webdriver?